# Issues with Hawtio after upgrading ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis, hawtio

I upgraded an ActiveMQ Artemis 1.5 project to 2.17, and some things started breaking. Is there any recommended way to force the exclusion of the automatic loading of a file called `index.html` from? I don't want the Hawtio interface but the pom seems to include it automatically in my Tomcat's `webapps` directory. It is interrupting the load of my regular index page. Excluding for example `artemis-console` from the pom will still add another different index file this time from `artemis-hawtio` branding also called `index.html`.

This one will create it. There is several html files created and some other stuff.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>artemis.playgroud.fake</groupId>
    <artifactId>ArtemisPlayground</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Fake Webapp</name>
    <description>Fake interproduct communication.</description>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.naming.factory.initial>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</java.naming.factory.initial>
        <compiler.version>2.5.1</compiler.version>
        <org.springframework.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.spring-security.version>5.2.3.RELEASE</org.spring-security.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-artemis</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-core-client</artifactId>
       <!--     <version>1.5.6</version>  -->
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>fake-service</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${compiler.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-timestamp>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How are you integrating ActiveMQ Artemis and Tomcat together? What pom are you referring to? As far as I'm aware there is no automated integration so you should have full control on how everything is deployed.

Comment: We use Apache Maven WAR plugin using Spring Framework (not boot).               <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId><artifactId>apache-artemis</artifactId>
<version>2.17.0</version>.    The WAR file ends up with a file named index.html in the web apps directory. The page is actually blank but if I look at the code contents it has the title "ActiveMQ Artemis Console".

Comment: I tried excluding artifactid  artemis-console but then another index.html file gets added to the WAR file this one says "hawtio-activemq-branding" with really nothing in it. In theory I guess I can remove the index.html file but my logging somehow broke after the upgrade also (that I still need to research). Maybe too big a jump from 1.5.6 to 2.17

Comment: Can you include your full `pom.xml` in your question? Are you embedding ActiveMQ Artemis in Tomcat via a WAR file? Please elaborate more fully on your use-case *in the question*.

Comment: It is a little big. Let me see if I can create a modified version without internal nexus repositories, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the `pom.xml`. However, it's still not clear exactly what you're trying to do. Why are you building the WAR file in the first place? Where does ActiveMQ Artemis fit in your application architecture? Are you trying to embed an ActiveMQ Artemis broker in your WAR file? Please elaborate.

Comment: That sample is a little convoluted just to get the same behavior. The app is a Tomcat website used for configuration with some webservices used by different applications to send information back and forth (i.e. contact, some transaction data, events, etc...). The services use Artemis. The configuration page allows different systems to connect and is able to modify/create multiple queues per system and monitor data throughput. It seems to be adding quite a few files to my webapps directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.apache.activemq:apache-artemis` dependency which you are using is a **`pom`** dependency type, i.e.:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-artemis</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
```

For your purposes (i.e. building a WAR) this means that Maven will scan all the modules in `apache-artemis` and include any which use `<packaging>war</packaging>`. In ActiveMQ Artemis version 2.17.0 this includes:

- `artemis-console`
- `activemq-branding`
- `artemis-plugin`

You can see Maven's war plugin process these when you run `mvn install` on your example `pom.xml`, e.g.:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.1:war (default-war) @ ArtemisPlayground ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [ArtemisPlayground] in [/path/to/fake-service/target/fake-service]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.apache.activemq:artemis-console]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.apache.activemq:activemq-branding]
[INFO] Processing overlay [ id org.apache.activemq:artemis-plugin]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [285 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /path/to/fake-service/target/fake-service.war
```

To be clear, **none** of these modules existed in ActiveMQ Artemis 1.5.0 which you were using previously. You can exclude these from your `pom.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-artemis</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artemis-console</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activemq-branding</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>artemis-plugin</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

That said, I'm not sure you actually need to configure this specific dependency in the first place. If all you really need to do is embed the broker you can probably just use this:

```xml
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>
         <version>2.17.0</version>
      </dependency>
```

Comment: Hey Justin, thanks for the help, that is great info. Moving from HornetQ to Artemis 1.5 was fairly straightforward this just threw me for a loop. Thanks

Comment: The transition from HornetQ to Artemis 1.x was mainly about rebranding and implementing a few features to get basic parity with ActiveMQ Classic. The switch to Artemis 2.0 was more significant with some big changes to the addressing model. Each subsequent release of 2.x has added more and more features. A web console based on Hawtio 1 was introduced in 2.3.0 which is where the `artemis-hawtio` module came from. That console was reworked to use Hawtio 2 in 2.16.0.

Comment: Excellent. That fixed my Index page, my logging and my service. Ran into other issues but those I can fix myself (permissions I think). The logging was interesting because I have no idea what happened (log4j) no log files were getting created and Tomcat was not complaining but now they are there. Thanks again.